# Solve an algebraic equation involving complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, education

Please, solve for $x$ and $y$,
$$(x+i)(3-iy)=1+13i, 
\quad x,y \in \text{Reals}$$

Comment: Apply the Distributive Property on the LHS

Comment: Assuming both $x$ and $y$ are reals?

Comment: Tell us what you think about the problem.

Answer (score 2):

$$(x+i)(3-iy) = 1+13i $$

$$  3x+y+i(3-xy) = 1+13i \implies \left\{
3x+y = 1 \atop
3-xy = 13
\right.$$

Now solve the system for x and y.